# Are any closed form solutions / upper bounds known for this product?

Tags: closed-form, products, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to get a closed form solution for the following product:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^t\left(1-\frac{a}{i^\beta}\right)
$$

where $\beta\in[1,2]$ and $a>0$.  In my application, an upper bound that converges to zero as $t\to\infty$ would also work.

---

Edit:

Extending the method linked by @DietrichBurde in the comments, we get

\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^t\left(1-\frac{a}{i^\beta}\right)
&=
\prod_{i=1}^t\frac{i^\beta-a}{i^\beta}
=
\frac{\prod_{i=1}^t i^\beta-a}{\prod_{i=1}^ti^\beta}
=
\frac{\prod_{i=1}^t i^\beta-a}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^ti\right)^\beta}
=
\frac{\prod_{i=1}^t i^\beta-a}{\Gamma\left(t+1\right)^\beta}
\end{align}
All that remains is to evaluate the numerator.
For $\beta=1$, we have
$$
\prod_{i=1}^t (i-a) 
= \frac{\Gamma(t-a+1)}{\Gamma(a+1)}
$$
and so
$$
\prod_{i=1}^t\left(1-\frac{a}{i}\right) = \frac{\Gamma(t-a+1)}{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(t+1)}
$$
as in the linked answer.

For $\beta=2$, we can factorize to get
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^t (i^2-a)
&= \prod_{i=1}^t (i-\sqrt{a})(i+\sqrt{a})
\\&= \left(\prod_{i=1}^t (i-\sqrt{a})\right)\left(\prod_{i=1}^t (i+\sqrt{a})\right)
\\&= \frac{\Gamma(t-\sqrt{a}+1)\Gamma(t+\sqrt{a}+1)}{\Gamma(-\sqrt{a}+1)\Gamma(\sqrt{a}+1)}
\\&= \frac{\Gamma(t-\sqrt{a}+1)\Gamma(t+\sqrt{a}+1)}{\Gamma(-\sqrt{a}+1)\Gamma(\sqrt{a})(a+1)}
\\&= \frac{\sin(\pi \sqrt a)}{\pi(a+1)}\Gamma(t-\sqrt{a}+1)\Gamma(t+\sqrt{a}+1)
\end{align}
where the last line follows from Eurler's reflection formula.
Therefore,
$$
\prod_{i=1}^t\left(1-\frac{a}{i^2}\right)
=
\frac{\sin(\pi \sqrt a)\Gamma(t-\sqrt{a}+1)\Gamma(t+\sqrt{a}+1)}{\pi(a+1)\Gamma(t+1)^2}.
$$
But now I'm not sure what to do with fractional $\beta$.
In particular, how can we rewrite $\prod_{i=1}^t (i^\beta -a)$ in a more useful form?

Comment: You might take the log; then you'd have a summation.

Comment: A related question is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93001/closed-form-expression-for-the-product-prod-limits-k-1n-left1-frac1?rq=1), for $\beta=1$ and $a$ replaced by $1/a$.

Answer (score 2):

For $\beta > 1$ and $a \in (0,1)$, an easy to derive upper bound is
$$\begin{align}\prod_{k=1}^p\left(1 - \frac{a}{k^\beta}\right)
&\le \exp\left(-\sum\limits_{k=1}^p\frac{a}{k^\beta}\right)
= \exp\left(-a\zeta(\beta) + a\sum\limits_{k=p+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^\beta}\right)\\
&\le \exp\left(-a\zeta(\beta)+a\int_p^\infty \frac{dx}{x^\beta}\right)
= \exp\left(-a\zeta(\beta)+ \frac{a}{\beta-1}p^{1-\beta}\right)
\end{align}
$$
If this upper bound is not tight enough, one can use the fact all coefficients in following expansion is negative $$\log(1-x) = -x - \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3} - \cdots$$
Repeat essentially the same argument, we find for any positive integer $m$,

$$\prod_{k=1}^p \left(1 - \frac{a}{k^\beta}\right)
\le \exp\left( -\sum\limits_{k=1}^p \sum\limits_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n}\frac{a^n}{k^{n\beta}}\right)
\le \exp\left[-\sum\limits_{n=1}^m \frac{a^n}{n} \left(\zeta(n\beta) - \frac{1}{n\beta-1}p^{1-n\beta}\right)\right]
$$

**Update**

For $\beta \in (0,1]$ and $a \in (0,1)$, we have
$$\begin{align}\prod_{k=1}^p\left(1 - \frac{a}{k^\beta}\right)
&\le \exp\left(-\sum\limits_{k=1}^p\frac{a}{k^\beta}\right)
= \exp\left[-a\left( 1 + \sum\limits_{k=2}^p\frac{1}{k^\beta}\right)\right]\\
&\le \exp\left[ -a\left(1 + \int_1^p \frac{dx}{x^\beta}\right)\right]\\
&=
\begin{cases}
\exp\left[ -a\left(1 + \frac{p^{1-\beta} - 1}{1-\beta}\right)\right], & \beta < 1\\
\exp(-a(1 + \log p)) = (pe)^{-a}, &\beta = 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
In both cases, the bound on RHS decrease to $0$ as $p$ increases.
By squeezing, we find the product converges to $0$ as $p \to \infty$.

Comment: I may have misunderstood something, but I believe your bound is trivial for large values of $p$ (which is the case I'm interested in).  Assume for a second that $a<1$.  Then the product I'm interested is guaranteed to be less than 1 as well for all $p$.  Your bound has a factor of $\exp(\tfrac{a}{\beta-1}p^{1-\beta})$, which grows unbounded as $p\to\infty$.  For the case of $a>1$, we have to factor out the first few terms (which will be a constant w.r.t. $p$), and the remaining terms are guaranteed to be less than 1 as well, so the same problem with the growth of the bound applies.

Comment: $\beta > 1 \implies p^{1-\beta} \to 0$ as $p \to \infty$.

Comment: Yes, but $\exp(p^{1-\beta}) \to 1$.

Comment: If $\beta > 1$, the $\prod_{k=1}^p\left(1 - \frac{a}{k^\beta}\right)$ converges to a finite value as $p \to \infty$, it make perfect sense for the leading $p$ factor $\exp(const. p^{1-\beta})$ to go to $1$.

Comment: I need a bound that converges to zero for my application.  In my recent edit, I come up with an explicit formula for $\beta=2$ which converges to a value greater than zero.  Now I'm curious if there are $\beta\in(0,1)$ which cause the product to converge to 0, and my hypothesis is yes.