# Combinatorially showing $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{2n\choose n}{4^n}}=0$

Tags: combinatorics, limits, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{2n\choose n}{4^n}}=0$. I found that using stirling's approximation, I can get:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{2n\choose n}{4^n}}=
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2*2^{2n}}}=
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{(\frac{2n}{e})^{2n}\sqrt{2\pi (2n)}}{((\frac{n}{e})^n\sqrt{2\pi n})^2*2^{2n}}}
=\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{2\sqrt{\pi n}}{2\pi n}}
=0
$$

But this seems inelegant where there should be a more elegant, combinatorial proof. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Seems like you might be able to use:
$$\binom{2n}n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2$$

Comment: There are $\binom{2n}{n}$ binary strings of length $2n$ that have exactly $n$ $1$-bits. There are $2^{2n} = 4^n$ total binary strings of length $2n$. If you could argue combinatorially that the former constitute a vanishing fraction of the latter, you'd have your result.

Comment: Hi note that you have $n\rightarrow 0$ in your limits

Comment: Stirling's formula in this context is a reflection of a deeper fact, namely the central limit theorem: ${2n \choose k} 4^{-k}$ is the probability that a sum of $2n$ Bernoulli random variables takes the value $k$, and these probabilities are governed by the central limit theorem as $n \to \infty$. The result you want can be interpreted in this light.

Comment: Whoops, that should be $4^{-n}$. Incidentally, I have no idea how to recover anything like the central limit theorem from combinatorial arguments; it seems to me to be a very probabilistic / analytic phenomenon.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/93049/73324) is a combinatorial proof that the term in the limit is decreasing (for $n=2^m$).

Comment: I think one reason it is hard to do this combinatorially is that the value is $O(1/\sqrt n)$, and $\sqrt{n}$ is hard to make combinatorial. But maybe $\binom{2n}{n}^2$ is easier to show is $O(4^{2n}/n)$?

Comment: Specifically, try to prove that $n\binom{2n}n^2\leq 2^{4n}$

Comment: @AustinMohr that was the original question.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288614/determine-lim-limits-n-to-inftyn-choose-fracn2-frac12n

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not a combinatorial approach, but a fun way of doing it is showing that $$\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{2n} x\; dx$$

Basically, writing $\cos x = \frac12\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)$. So $\cos^{2n} x$ has constant term $\binom{2n}{n}/4^n$.

Since $\cos^{2n} x\to 0$ for almost all $x$, it is pretty easy to show that the above integral tends to zero as $n\to\infty$.
Specifically, on the intervals $(\varepsilon,\pi-\varepsilon)\cup(\pi+\varepsilon,2\pi-\varepsilon)$, $\cos^{2n}x\to 0$ uniformly.

Answer (score 10):

Here’s a non-combinatorial argument that avoids Stirling’s approximation.

$$\begin{align*}
p_n\triangleq\frac{\binom{2n}n}{4^n}&=\frac{(2n)!}{(2^nn!)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{(2n)!(2n-1)!!^2}{(2n)!^2}\\\\
&=\frac{(2n-1)!!^2}{(2n)!}\\\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k}\\\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\ln p_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(-\sum_{m\ge 1}\frac1{m(2k)^m}\right)\le-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}=-\frac12H_n\;,$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$-th [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). The harmonic series diverges, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln p_n=-\infty$, and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=0$.

Note: The [double factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) $(2n-1)!!$ is the product of the odd positive integers not exceeding $2n-1$:

$$(2n-1)!!=\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}\;.$$

Comment: Should define $!!$ somewhere - not everybody is well-versed in its meaning.

Comment: This is just the proof of a weak form of Stirlings estimate, but shown in a way that one may not recognize it.  It would be equivalent to derive a weak form of Stirlings estimate from first principles and then apply that.

Comment: @Thomas: Don’t you mean ‘not everybody is well-versed in its meaning!!’ ? :-)

Comment: @Eric: Sure, but it still avoids Stirling’s approximation itself and uses tools immediately available to anyone who has had standard freshman calculus and a basic exposure to binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 10):

Another was is to use the generating function of the central binomial coefficients, that is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{4^{n}}x^{n}.$$ We will make use of the fact that $x_{n}=\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{4^{n}}$  is a monotically decreasing sequence to make sure there are no oscillations.  It is monotonic since $$x_{n+1}=\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{4^{n}}\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{4\left(n+1\right)^{2}}=x_{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+2}\right).$$ Taking the indefinite integral of both sides of the generating function, we have that for $|x|<1,$ $$2-2\sqrt{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{4^{n}}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$ Now, the left hand side converges as $x\rightarrow1$  from the left, and so, since the series has strictly positive coefficients, the right hand side must converge as well. This implies that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{4^{n}}\frac{1}{n+1}$$ is a convergent series, and since the coefficients $\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{4^{n}}$ are monotonically decreasing, the divergence of the harmonic series implies that we must have $$\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{4^{n}}\rightarrow0.$$

**Added Details:**  Based on the comments, I thought I would give a precise proof of why the series must converge, without appealing to [Littlewood's Tauberian theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem#Littlewood.27s_extension_of_Tauber.27s_theorem) The proof only requires that the coefficients of the power series, $a_n$, are nonnegative.  Let $a_n\geq0$, $s_m=\sum_{n=0}^m a_n$ be the partial sums, and suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}\leq C$ for all $x\in(0,1),$ for some positive constant $C$. Then for $x\in(0,1),$ $$s_{m}=\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_{n}\left(1-x^{n}\right)+\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_{n}x^{n}$$ $$\leq(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_{n}\left(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}\right)+C$$

$$\leq(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{m}na_{n}+C.$$ Taking $x$ sufficiently close to $1$, we can make $(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{m}na_{n}\leq 1$, and so it follows that $s_{m}\leq C+1.$ This means that $s_m$ is monotonically increasing and bounded, its limit, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ must converge.  In particular, our series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{4^{n}(n+1)},$$ is convergent.

Comment: Actually, my problem was that you are seemingly using Tauber's theorem to conclude the series converges at $x=1$; but that requires that you check a hypothesis which actually implies that the coefficients go to zero.

Comment: The last thing you quote is usually stated in books as follows: "If $a_n$ is a sequence of positive monotonically decreasing terms, and $\sum a_n$ converges, then $na_n\to 0$."

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Things are simplified significantly when it is monotonic and positive.

Comment: You are not using Abel's theorem but one of its partial converses. for example, littlewood's theorem as given [here](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/amstext-17-prev.pdf)

Comment: There is a Tauberian theorem that says: "If $a_n\geq 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\sum a_n x^n$ exists and is $A$ then $\sum a_n$ exists and is $A$."

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, PeterTamaroff: I added a proof that the series converges.

Comment: Cool. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: That's a lot of work after you've essentially got that $$x_n=C\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)$$ which converges to zero by various rules about infinite products, since $\sum \frac{1}{2n}$ doesn't converge...

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I think "a combinatorial approach:" Note that $\binom{2n}{n}$ is the number of $n$ element subsets of a $2n$ element set. Consider the quantities $\binom{2n}{n+i},\,i=1,\ldots,k$ for some small $k$ (relative to $n$). We have the relationship $\binom{2n}{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$, and in general, $\binom{2n}{n+k} = \frac{n-k+1}{n+k}\binom{2n}{n+k-1}$. Now for any $k$, we can choose $n$ so large that $\frac{n-k+1}{n+k}$ is at least $1-\frac{1}{2k}$. This gives us the estimate $\binom{2n}{n+k} \geq (1-\frac{1}{2k})\binom{2n}{n+k-1} \geq \cdots \geq (1-\frac{1}{2k})^k\binom{2n}{n} \geq \frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}$. Therefore, for any $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and when $n$ is large enough, the number of $n+i$ element subsets of a $2n$ element set is at least $\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}$. Hence, $\frac{k}{2}\binom{2n}{n} \leq 4^n$. Now, let $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$
\begin{align}
(n+2)(2n+1)^2
&=4n^3+12n^2+9n+2\\
&\le4n^3+12n^2+12n+4\\
&=(n+1)(2n+2)^2\tag1
\end{align}
$$
which shows that
$$
\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\right)^2\le\frac{n+1}{n+2}\tag2
$$

Since
$$
\frac{\frac1{4^{n+1}}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}{\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\le\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n+2}}\tag3
$$
we can take products to get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}
&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\frac1{4^{k+1}}\binom{2k+2}{k+1}}{\frac1{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}}\tag{4a}\\
&\le\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k+2}}\tag{4b}\\[6pt]
&=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$
which shows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=0\tag5
$$

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of combinatorial proofs,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{2k}{k}}{2^{2k}}\frac{\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}}{2^{2(n-k)}}=1.
$$
The key step of [a combinatorial proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37984/) is that $p_k=\binom{2k}k2^{-2k}$ is the probability that random path with $2k$ steps $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ doesn't touch $x$-axis after the start. So now we see that sequence $p_k$ is monotonic.
But then the first identity obviously implies $p_k\to0$ (if $\forall k\;p_k\gt\epsilon$, $1=\sum p_kp_{N-k}\gt N\epsilon\gt1$)

Comment: (There are of course other ways to prove that random walk on a line eventually hits the origin)

Comment: Your first identity is also a key part of this delightful paper: Johan Wästlund, "[An Elementary Proof of the Wallis Product Formula for pi](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~wastlund/monthly.pdf)", *Am. Math. Monthly* **114** (10), 2007, pp.914–917.

Answer (score 0):

A probabilistic approach that may content you. Let $p_n={2n\choose n}/4^n$; $p_n$ is the probability that a random walker with equally likely steps $-1$ and $+1$ is found at the origin after $2n$ steps. We can prove that $p_n\to 0$ using the fact that a binomial distribution "flattens out" as $n$ gets large.

**Lemma.** For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ ,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n\choose n+k}{2n\choose n} = 1.$$

**Proof.**
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n\choose n+k}{2n\choose n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-k)!(n+k)!}{(n!)^2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+k)(n+k-1)...(n+1)}{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}\\
&=1
\end{align*}

Let us now suppose BWOC that $p_n$ does not tend to $0$. Then there must exist some $\epsilon>0$ such that the set $S=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:p_n>\epsilon\}$ is unbounded. Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $\frac{2}{N}<\epsilon$. By our lemma we can find $n_1,n_2,...,n_N$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_j&\implies \left|\frac{2n\choose n+j}{2n\choose n}-1\right|<\frac12\\
&\implies {2n\choose n+j}>\frac{2n\choose n}{2}\\
&\implies \frac{2n\choose n+j}{4^n}>\frac{p_n}{2}
\end{align*}
for $1\leq j\leq N$. Now, given the unboundedness of $S$, we may find $m\in S$ such that $m\geq \max(n_1,...,n_N)$. Then, observe that for every $1\leq j\leq N$
\begin{align*}
\frac{2m\choose m+j}{4^m}&>\frac{p_m}{2}\\
&>\frac{\epsilon}2>\frac1{N}.
\end{align*}
Therefore
$$\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{2m\choose m+j}{4^m}>N\frac1{N}=1.$$
But this contradicts that
$$\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{2m\choose m+j}{4^m}<\sum_{j=0}^{2m}\frac{2m\choose j}{4^m}=1.$$
Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=0$.