# Limit $\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\frac{\left(n!\right)^2\cdot4^n\cdot n}{\left(2n\right)!}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial, divergent-series

I am currently trying to calculate the following limit of sequence: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\frac{\left(n!\right)^2\cdot4^n\cdot n}{\left(2n\right)!}}$$ I need it to prove that a series diverges, but I really can't find a way to solve this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

(I really hope I'm not missing anything obvious!)

**Edit**: You are all absolutely right, I apologize for the lack of context. What is actually going on is that working with a function series, in particular the power series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{\left(2n\right)!}x^n}$$
I needed to find pointwise and total convergence$^1$ for it.
To do that I tried to find the radius of convergence using D'Alembert's criterion$^2$ and I found the radius to be $\rho =4$. Therefore my pointwise convergence would be for $\left|x\right|<\rho$.

At this point, I needed to check convergence in the points that coincide with the extremities of the convergence radius, so $x=4$ and $x=-4$. I am currently working on $x=4$. Inserting the value in the original function series I get the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{\left(2n\right)!}4^n}$$

I need to find the behaviour of this series. Given how I found the radius of convergence, both the ratio test and the root test are completely useless. I saw Wolfram also uses the integral test, I honestly don't know it, but still, it says it's inconclusive.

I've decided to use the limit comparison test, I don't know if it was the right choice, but either way, since I do know that the series should be divergent, I took $a_n=\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{\left(2n\right)!}4^n$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and that's how I got the limit that this question is about: the limit comparison test will be based on the result of:

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\frac{a_n}{b_n}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\frac{\left(n!\right)^2\cdot4^n\cdot n}{\left(2n\right)!}}=l$$

We know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{b_n}$ is the harmonic series and is divergent, therefore, if $\lim_{n\to +\infty}{\frac{a_n}{b_n}}=+\infty$ (which, according to Wolfram, is actually the result of the limit) then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ would also be a divergent series. So, yeah, I just need to solve the limit now.

This should be the complete context, if there's something that wasn't clear I don't have any problem clarifying it! And once again, thanks in advance for any response!

**Edit 2**: In some of the comments there are answers to what I was looking for, but I had already written the context part so I'll post it anyway, as it may be useful to someone someday!

(if you notice I've written anything wrong, please let me know)

$^1$*I believe in English it should simply be known as the result of the Weierstrass M-test, in other words, the series converges uniformly and absolutely when there's "total" convergence.*

$^2$*This one should be the ratio test I think. Since I can't find a lot about it being applied to power series in English resources, I'll specify that given a power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n x^n}$, the radius of convergence is $\rho =\frac{1}{l}$, where $l$ can be expressed as $l=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\left|a_{n+1}\right|}{\left|a_{n}\right|}}$, when the limit exists.*

Comment: Have you looked at the ratio $n+1$ term / $n$ term?  This is a generic method to attempt for sequences based on factorials and/or exponentials.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to tell us what you've tried.  In addition to being required by the site's rules, it's common courtesy because it will save us effort by preventing us from making suggestions that you've already tried.  I suspect from what you've written that this limit is the result you get from applying the ratio test to the series you're interested in, but since $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$, it doesn't tell you anything useful about the limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combinatorially showing $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{2n\choose n}{4^n}}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434144/combinatorially-showing-lim-n-to-infty-frac2n-choose-n4n-0) (this is an automatic comment. You can close the question as a duplicate yourself)

Comment: @Marco Even tho the post did answer my question it did so in a way that used theorems and concepts I wasn't familiar with and that I don't think I'll even study in my uni courses at all, so I decided to write an answer that doesn't make use of them

Answer (score 1):

So, I believe I have come to a working solution, mostly based on the answer provided by [@RyszardSzwarc](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/715896/ryszard-szwarc). He deserves the credit, I'll simply be expanding on what he wrote for it to be clearer.

As he said in his answer, we can write $4^n$ as $\left(1+1\right)^{2n}$. We can then use the binomial theorem:

$$\left(x+y\right)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^k}\text{, where }\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!\left(n-k\right)!}$$

in our specific case, it will become:

$$\left(1+1\right)^{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}{\binom{2n}{k}}$$

Considering that $0<n<2n$, and that, for this reason, $\binom{2n}{n}$ is one of the terms of our summation, we can get to the following conclusion:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}{\binom{2n}{k}}>\binom{2n}{n}\implies 4^n>\binom{2n}{n}$$

We did all of this for simply one reason:

$$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{n!\left(2n-n\right)!}=\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(n!\right)^2}\implies 4^n>\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(n!\right)^2}$$

At this point, [@RyszardSzwarc](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/715896/ryszard-szwarc) suggested to simply put the $n$ from the limit into the mix to prove that it does indeed approach $\infty$. This makes sense, but, as [@zwim](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/399263/zwim) pointed out, the limit goes to infinity without the $n$ too, and this can be proved easily.

If we consider $\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{\left(2n\right)!}$ for any given $n$, we will end up with a fraction that will have:

- As the numerator, the factorial $n!$
- As the denominator, the factorial $\left(2n\right)!$ divided by $n!$.

If you think about it, dividing $\left(2n\right)!$ for $n!$ is just eliminating the last $n$ terms of $\left(2n\right)!$, for example:

$$n=5\text{, }\quad\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{\left(2n\right)!}=\frac{5^2\cdot 4^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 2^2\cdot 1^2}{10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}=\frac{5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6}$$

Clearly, when $n\to \infty$, $\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{\left(2n\right)!}\to 0$. This has some important implications: first of all, it means that the statement: $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(n!\right)^2}}=\infty$ is also valid, and second: we have a new way to write our limit:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{\left(2n\right)!}4^n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{\left(n!\right)^2/\left(n!\right)^2}{\left(2n\right)!^{}/\left(n!\right)^2}4^n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{4^n}{\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(n!\right)^2}}}$$

At this point, all we have to do is to remember the first part of this proof: even tho both parts of the limit are approaching $\infty$, we know that $4^n$ is always greater than $\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(n!\right)^2}$, plus, if we were to calculate the limit of the difference between $4^n$ and $\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{\left(2n\right)!}$, we would easily find it to be $\infty$.

This means that the two will never converge: they'll only keep accentuating how much faster the first term will approach $\infty$ compared to the second one.

Given all these conditions it appears clear that, as the index $n$ approaches infinity, the limit will inevitably be equal to $\infty$: $4^n$ will be a continually larger number, $\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(n!\right)^2}$ instead, while constantly growing, will also become infinitely small *when compared* to $4^n$

**Edit**: I forgot about $n$, clearly when the rest of the limit approaches $\infty$, if we then multiply everything for another sequence that also approaches $\infty$ the limit will still hold true.